# How to use update_or_create on django post_save?

Tags: django

```
class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
        Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                    null=True,blank=True)      

    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
            def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
                teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,
                                                                Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels,
                                                                Courses=instance.Courses)
            for each in teachers:
                if created or teachers.exists():
                    print("if")
                    StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create_or_update(
                        pk=each.id,
                        Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                        Subject_Section_Teacher=each

                    )
```

Inserting data is working perfectly but when I update the **existing data** it creates another record not update

what i tried the solution of mr @ruddra,

```
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
                Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                defaults= {'Subject_Section_Teacher': each}

            )
```

it works ! but when i tried to save another record with multiple related data, it only save 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create_or_update(
    pk=each.id,  # <-- this code
    Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
    Subject_Section_Teacher=each
)
```

Is it correct? Then `StudentsEnrollmentSubject` primary key will be same as teachers, and it might create `IntegrityError`.

Now, as per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), you need to provide `defaults={key:value}` value which will be updated in the Table. So it should be like this:

```
StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
    Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
    defaults= {'Subject_Section_Teacher':each}
)
```

---

### Update:

I don't think you should use `update_or_create` signal. if you use `update_or_create`, also number of teachers won't be same when you change `StudentsEnrollmentRecord`'s course or education level etc.

To get older instance, use `pre_save` signal:

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    # ...

    @receiver(pre_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def get_older_instance(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
           instance._old_instance = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.object.get(pk=instance.pk)
        except StudentsEnrollmentRecord.DoesNotExist:
           instance._old_instance = None

    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if not created:
           old_instance = instance._old_instance
           if older_instance.Courses != instance.Courses or \
              older_instance.Sections != instance.Sections or \
              older_instance.Education_Levels != instance.Education_Levels:

                 StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(
                   Students_Enrollment_Records=instance
                 ).delete()
           else:
               return None


       teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,  Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels, Courses=instance.Courses)
       for each in teachers:
             StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
                Students_Enrollment_Records_id=instance.pk,
                Subject_Section_Teacher=each
             )
```

Here I am deleting all the `StudentsEnrolledSubject` if any value from `Courses`, `Sections`, `Eduction_levels` changes from older instance. Because as I said earlier, number of teachers won't be same. So I deleted those instance and created new ones with new teachers.

Comment: it should be `update_or_create` :) Please see the updated answer

Comment: it work sir, but the when i save it, only one record save in my database,

Comment: when i removed the pk=each.id, only one record save,

Comment: Please see the update section and better to use it with caution. Make sure to backup your database before using it. Because you might lose data

Comment: i get this error sir **cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object** from this line ""old_instance = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.get(instance.pk)""

Comment: oh, it should be StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.get(pk=instance.pk). Updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201983/discussion-between-kaito-and-ruddra).